# Solaris 10 Jumpstart the interactive installer

Tags: solaris, jumpstart

With Solaris 10, can I use jumpstart to partially define the system and have the installer then prompt the user for anything else?

This would be like the kickstart file behaviour for RHEL's Anaconda install system, anything which hasn't been declared in the kickstart file will be prompted for.  So with this I can specify some common base settings like timezone, keyboard, packages, etc while leaving settings like network config to be defined by the person installing the system.

Is it possible to do this with Solaris 10 (update 8)?  The main reason is that I need to load a driver for the HP storage controller (CPQary3) found in, for example, the G5 servers.  I've successfully installed the driver into the miniroot so that the installer can see the disks, but this doesn't follow through to the installed system.  If I set up a jumpstart profile with post-install script, then the interactive GUI doesn't show up.  If I don't configure a profile, but specify a finish script then the interactive GUI doesn't show up.

Any ideas?  Maybe I could slipstream this into the default install image itself?

Edit: not that it will likely make a difference but I'm hosting all the network boot files on RHEL (which was fine when I only wanted to PXE boot Linux, but Solaris has been a whole new kind of pain).

Answer (score 0):

You can make additional 3rd-party packages available to Jumpstart via HTTP with the "package" keyword.  The packages will need to be in datastream format (single file, rather than a directory structure).  Specify them in your Jumpstart profile like:

```
package CPQary3 add http://my.server.com/path/to/CPQary3 timeout 5
```

See an example at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18752_01/html/821-1911/preparecustom-53442.html

Comment: Problem was that by using jumpstart, I didn't get any GUI pop up to assist the installation.  What I wanted to achieve was to specify only some settings, while leaving others up to the person installing the OS (just like can be done with RHEL).